# IE exploit doesn't work when loading in iframe

Tags: exploit, internet-explorer

I am doing pentest for some company and about to use IE public exploit to take over a client. I need to run html including IE exploit , with an iFrame, but I can’t run the iFrame in windows 7 properly. the exploit dosen’t properly works, even it didn’t crash in windows 7 with iFrame. I dont know what’s the problem. for example in this code

[image]

"test.html" is IE public exploit(CVE-2014-1770) including javascript code & Heapspray.
the exploit link is: https://github.com/wchen-r7/metasploit-framework/commit/49551013cce106a4bd6a3477319e1d3466c615bb .
the exact code works without Iframe but when I load it from an iframe, it doesn’t work as it should in windows 7 & crashing in windows xp. I change this for windows 7 manually.

Curious if you had similar experience with IE exploits and iframe and any idea why this happen and how to fix the issue ?

Comment: -1 your question does not contain enough relevant information

Comment: What exploit is this? Does this exploit have a link?  or a CVE number? What is test.html?